# Annoyances of Flex - Associative Array

Tags: apache-flex, associative-array

I have an associative array and while iterating through this array, using foreach loop. Flex is loosing the order. This is so annoying.

Why is this happening?

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the specification, the values in an associative array are not "ordered".

If you need to get values in a specified order, you'll need to sort the keys yourself.

Answer (score 5):

[Associative arrays](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_4.html) are implementation of the [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure, and hence are unordered by nature.